# Generate folder-icon with preview of its contents using PHP

Tags: php, thumbnails

I've got several folders, each containing several images. What I want to do is:

1. open directory with php and display the folders into the browser
2. the folder-icon should already display a preview of its contents
3. If there are too many images, only a subset (maybe max 4) should be displayed

U may know this from Windows:

[image]

.
I'd be glad if i could handle it like that or similar to the Windows solution

Comment: As a general hint: You will need AJAX and a script that pre creating those previews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is way to broad but I guess we could start with the fact that PHP offers two main solutions for image processing:

- [Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) (ImageMagick)
- [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Basically, what you want to do is have a base *folder* icon image and overlay thumbnails of its contents' previews on top of it.

How you get these thumbnails is depends on your setup. Is that a Windows server with previews already generated by the OS that you can extract and use? Do you need to generate them from scratch? What kind of data do you have readily available?

As for reading data of the filesystem, PHP has some excellent [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.file.php) online on Filesystem IO.

Comment: I guess I have to create the thumbnails from scatch. I already feared that this wont be a straight-forward task, but I thought that php probably offers some build-in solution. Ok, this means a lot of reading. Thanks for giving me some point to start at!

Comment: There are methods in imagick and gd to create thumbnails from images, so that should be quite easy. As well as creating composite images (overlaying one on top of the other). However, you need to figure out which is the 'source' image you will use to create the thumbnails.